# Consuming and Provide webservice to client

Tags: java, web-services

I got a requirement to implement a website in java which will utilize another web service.

Here is the scenario I am providing the product compare results to client and assume i am using amazon and other web services. Initially client invoke our web service and then we fetch results from merchants.

I don't want complete solution  just look for consuming and create web service in java example. I searched on google but couldn't found relevant example. I prefer if example is using eclipse :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One swift Google search revealed many, many tutorials on this topic, not least Sun's own [Java Web Services Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/). I suggest starting there, and then posting here if you have a coding issue you can't resolve.